# ZK Error Handling: During initial request vs. AJAX request

Tags: error-handling, zk

I want to handle errors in my webapp as gracefully as possible.
Of course, I've [RTFM](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Error_Handling) and added the following to my `web.xml` file:

```
<!-- WEB-INF/web.xml -->
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>    
    <location>/error.zul</location>    
</error-page>
```

This is basic [Java webapp error handling](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/crazybob/archive/2004/02/exception_handl.html) and works great. As ZK is an AJAXy framework, an error could be thrown after the page has been rendered and so ZK provides it's own error handling for this also:

```
<!-- zk.xml -->
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>    
    <location>/zk/common/error.zul</location>    
</error-page>
```

This works great also, however, they don't play nice. When an error is thrown during an AU request, the ZK error message displays as it should but I get the following to `stderr`:

```
Feb 26, 2013 10:37:04 PM org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet handleError:273
WARNING: Failed to load the error page: /zk/common/error.zul
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:198)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:168)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.handleError(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:267)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:138)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doPost(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:149)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Feb 26, 2013 10:37:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet auEngine threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:198)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.ServletDspContext.getOut(ServletDspContext.java:113)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.impl.TextNode.interpret(TextNode.java:44)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.impl.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:51)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.impl.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:60)
    at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.DspExtendlet.service(DspExtendlet.java:92)
    at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.web0(ClassWebResource.java:583)
    at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.web(ClassWebResource.java:569)
    at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.service(ClassWebResource.java:260)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:392)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:464)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.Servlets.include(Servlets.java:882)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.Utils.handleError(Utils.java:143)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.handleError(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:278)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:138)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doPost(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:149)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Feb 26, 2013 10:37:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet zkLoader threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:198)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.ServletDspContext.getOut(ServletDspContext.java:113)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.impl.TextNode.interpret(TextNode.java:44)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.impl.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:51)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.impl.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:60)
    at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.DspExtendlet.service(DspExtendlet.java:92)
    at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.web0(ClassWebResource.java:583)
    at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.web(ClassWebResource.java:569)
    at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.service(ClassWebResource.java:260)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:392)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:464)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.Servlets.include(Servlets.java:882)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.Utils.handleError(Utils.java:143)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.handleError(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:278)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:138)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doPost(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:149)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Feb 26, 2013 10:37:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=java.lang.Throwable, location=/error.zul]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:198)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.ServletDspContext.getOut(ServletDspContext.java:113)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.impl.TextNode.interpret(TextNode.java:44)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.impl.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:51)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.impl.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:60)
    at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.DspExtendlet.service(DspExtendlet.java:92)
    at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.web0(ClassWebResource.java:583)
    at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.web(ClassWebResource.java:569)
    at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.service(ClassWebResource.java:260)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:392)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:464)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.zkoss.web.servlet.Servlets.include(Servlets.java:882)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.Utils.handleError(Utils.java:143)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.handleError(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:278)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:138)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doPost(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:149)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Again, this is when the ZK specific error handler (at `/zk/common/error.zul`) intercepts the error. According to the stack trace, it seems as though the error propagates on to the normal Java webapp error handler (at `/error.zul`).

If an error occurs when the page is first rendering, the normal error handler (at `/error.zul') displays instead of the page as expected, no problems logged.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?
Can/should I be doing something on my ZK error handler to stop the error from propagating?

Answer (score 0):

you can use an Initiator to handle exceptions that occurs when ZK Loader renders a page. Tag used is

```
<?init class="com.foo.MyInitial"?>
```

You need to implement [Initiator](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/util/Initiator.html).

Hope this helps.

Reference : [Link](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/UI%20Patterns/Page%20Initialization)